# fancybox href ="imageURL" using populated image1 in datalist1

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

i have fancybox in my gallery that are populated in my web page using datalist1. 
my fancybox image viewer is working when I set the imageUrl and href value like this

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="~/Image/Slides/Image1.jpg">
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/Image/Slides/Image1.jpg" runat="server" Width="50%"/></a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
```

now the problem is, 
i'm not setting the ImageUrl my code behind does
so i set the imageUrl using Eval, Like this

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Value") %>' runat="server" Width="50%"/>
```

and  here's my C# code for populating

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Image/Slides/"));
            List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
            foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                files.Add(new ListItem(fileName, "~/Image/Slides/" + fileName));

            }
            DataList1.DataSource = files;
            DataList1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void Upload(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Image/Slides/") + fileName);
            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
        }
    }
```

so to be able to use the fancybox I have to set the value of href, 
so I tried to to set it like this

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns = "4" CellPadding = "4" 
        Width="535px">
<ItemTemplate>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width = "120px">
        <tr>
            <td align = "center">
            <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href='<%# Eval("Value") %>'>
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Value") %>' runat="server" Width="50%" class="fancybox"/></a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align = "center">
                <%# Eval("Text") %>


            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</ItemTemplate>
```

notice the `href='<%# Eval("Value") %>'` so meaning to say what ever the value of imageurl that will be the value of the href in my mind that it should be
but its not because everytime i click the image my fancybox is not working 
here's what happened after clicking the image 
[image]

please help me 
thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the HTML `a` tag to `asp:HyperLink` which belongs to `System.Web.UI.WebControls` like this.

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" CssClass="fancybox" rel="group" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Value") %>'>
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" 
        ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Value") %>' 
        Width="50%" />
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Reason: "~/" is won't resolve for HTML controls

Comment: wow thank you very much for responding and providing a very helpful information ^_^ i really appreciated your effort sir naveen ^_^